# FFmpeg amerge filter - Continue on with longest audio stream

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, audio, ffmpeg

I have a video that already has 1 audio stream. I have another `m4a` file that I want to merge with the already-existing audio stream in the video.

The `m4a` file is about 10 seconds shorter than the other audio stream, and according to the [`FFmpeg` docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge):

> *If inputs do not have the same duration, the output will stop with the shortest.*

But I want it to continue on with the longer audio stream (but still have both streams merged into one.

Here's the current command I'm using, which just stops the audio once the shortest audio stream finishes:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i shorteraudio.m4a -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=-2:720,format=yuv420p[v];[0:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map [v] -map [a] output.mp4
```

Is it possible to do what I want to do with just one FFmpeg command?

Comment: Did you try to use `amix` filter instead?

Answer (score 2):

If the 2nd input is known to have a shorter audio stream, you can pad its length so that the first becomes shorter.

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i shorteraudio.m4a -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=-2:720,format=yuv420p[v];[1:a]apad[a1];[0:a][a1]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map [v] -map [a] output.mp4`